How to create dropdown in mvc to select object
As we can select object in angular, is there any way that I make asp.net Dropdown to select the object.
I have a list in which there is Id, CountryName, CurrencyCode. I want CurrencyCode to be selected as well.
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <option *ngFor="let myModel of countries" [ngValue]="myModel">{{myModel.name}}</option>
</select>

Just for CurrencyCode I don't want to write extra code to find it in a list and assign CurrencyCode when matched. Currently it is only selecting ID and displaying CountryName.
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, new SelectList(Model.Countries.OrderBy(x => x.CountryName), "Id", "CountryName", Model.Countries.Select(x => x.Id)).OrderBy(r => r.Text), "----- Select Country-----", new { @id = "ddlCountry", @class = "form-control select2" })


There isn´t any object binding in MVC it´s a one way street for the most part. Once rendered you can either get the value of the dropdown with document.getElementById('dropdownId').value in JS code and then do whatever you want with it, or post the value as part of a form submit.

Angular is data-oriented but razor page is DOM-oriented, so that Angular could select model object, but razor page couldn't. But we could still have a workaround to put the CurrencyCode in another attribute beyond the value and text which is similar to @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Id", "CountryName", new {@id="ddlCountry",@code=model.CurrencyCode })

Yeah Tiny Wang, I totally understand. But I think we should have such option to select whole model/object.

thank you for your kind reply and I'm afraid you might try to use blazor into your razor web app.

i have nearly same logic extension for EnumTypes that holds EnumValues
namespace BraInvest_CourseManagement.AppCode.Extensions {
  public static partial class Extension {
    public static List<SelectListItem> GenerateSelectList<TEnum>() where TEnum
        : Enum {
      List<TEnum> enumValues =
          Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>().ToList();

      List<SelectListItem> selectList =
          new (){new SelectListItem{Text = "None", Value = null}};

      enumValues.ForEach(
          enumValue => selectList.Add(new SelectListItem{
              Text = GetDescription(enumValue), Value = enumValue.ToString()}));

      return selectList;
    }
  }
}

Path : Areas.Admin.Controllers
    private readonly List<SelectListItem>
    ? _categories = Extension.GenerateSelectList<Category>();

[Authorize(Policy = "admin.blogpost.create")]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["Categories"] = new SelectList(_categories, "Value", "Text");

            return View();
        }

Path : Areas.Admin.Views.Blog.Create.cshtml
    < div class
= "form-group row" > < label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" asp-for="Category">Category</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select asp-for="Category" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Categories"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="Category" class
= "text-danger" > </ span></ div></ div>
    


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
